# A problem in modular arithmetic.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given large $n\in\Bbb N$ is there many $a,b\in(n,2n)$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $q,r\in(n^4,2n^4)$ with $\gcd(a,bq)=\gcd(ar,b)=1$ and $c,d\in(n^3,2n^3)$ with $-n<-x=q\bmod c,-y=r\bmod d<0$ with $\gcd(a,x)=1$ and $\gcd(b,y)=1$ such that if $u=ca^{-1}{b^2}\bmod q, v=db^{-1}{a^2}\bmod r$ then ${n}^{2+\beta}<u,v<{n}^{2+\beta'}$ at a fixed $0<\beta<\beta'\ll1$?

Comment: When you write $a,b\in(n,2n)$ do you mean $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n<a<2n$ (and similarly for $b$)?

Comment: using gcd criterion forces your picks to be in z.